# How can I get the URL from the default browser to use in my custom browser?

Tags: android, browser

I am developing an Android app in which a type of browser will be included. As the user tries to open a URL, an intent resolver asks the user whether they want to complete the action using  the default browser or a custom browser. This part of my app is completed. Now I want to ask, if the user chooses to open the link in my custom browser, how can I access that URL?

Currently, if the user chooses my browser they got blank web view, as I am unable to get the URL which I have to open in my webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your custom browser is starting in response to an intent, the target URL should be contained in that intent for you to extract.

Answer (score 1):

> If the user chooses to open the link in my custom browser, how can I access that URL?

Call `getIntent().getData()` to get the `Uri` the user is trying to open.

Comment: thanks for ur ans...i got the url..but stil my webview is unable to load this url...it is not giving any error..so i m unable to trace this.plz help